# How do I write a multiline string with only the first line indented?

Tags: yaml

I have a multi-line string whose first line is indented, but subsequent lines are not. **How do I represent this in YAML?**

```
      12    24
30    60    53
36    66    59
```

YAML sees the de-dentation and considers it the end of the string.

Here's one way I could do it. But it would be nice if I could more easily cut-and-paste the values without modifying the string so much.

```
"      12    24\n\
\30    60    53\n\
\36    66    59"
```

Comment: See also a complete comparison over multi-lines strings in YAML at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/248390

Answer (score 4):

You can  do this somewhat more easy by using the the [literal block style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) combined with an appropriate block header doing [explicit block indentation indication](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979) (instead of automatic) and block [strip chomping](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2794534):

```
|1-
       12    24
 30    60    53
 36    66    59
```

Unfortunately there is no way to reduce the indentation further to 0, as there would be no indication as to where the block would end and a next item started. It would probably have been better if the specification had allowed zero or negative indentation for literal blocks while requiring number of lines to be specified ( `|0:3-` ), but that is not in the specs.